# How to filter results from firebase without looping through the whole snapshot in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I used to loop through everything that came from firebase using `forEach` and start adding those I need in another list. but I knew there is a direct query I can do. and here is the code i used :

```dart
  void findRoom() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('rooms')
        .where('from_id', isEqualTo: currentProfile.id.)
        .orderBy('from_id')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) => print(document.data()));
    }
    );
  }
```

But it breaks down at the lines `snapshots()` with the error

> Unhandled Exception: RangeError (takeCount): Invalid value: Not greater than or equal to 0: -1

Comment: Do not `orderBy` the same field that you use in `where`. I don't know that that will solve your problem, but it's unnecessary for sure.

Comment: it seems that you're not gathering information from the querySnapshot and when you try to loop through it, it fails with the error. Please try to print the content before looping through it and update the question with the results